# Mysql: Query not working properly, not selecting 12:00 in where between

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

mysql `between` not working as expected.
Query I have now:

```
Table::where(function ($query) use ($time_in, $time_out) {
            $query->orWhereRaw("? between time_in AND time_out", [$time_in.":00"])
            ->orWhereRaw("? between time_in AND time_out", [$time_out.":00"])
            ->orWhereRaw("time_in between ? AND ?", [$time_in.":00", $time_out.":00"])
            ->orWhereRaw("time_out between ? AND ?", [$time_in.":00", $time_out.":00"]); 
        })->get();
```

I am trying to get all the data from `Table` if my `time_in` & `time_out` is between them or if they are between in my `time_in` and `time_out`.
what is not working here is:
If `$time_in = 12:00` and `$time_out = 3:00` then my query won't select the data which has `time_in` of `11:00` to `time_out = 4`. But if I change my `$time_in` to `1:00` then the query works. Its not working if I have a data of `11:00` or `12:00` and If i check if my `11:00` or `12:00` is between them

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff for now, and instead see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: By 12, do you mean 12pm, or 12am which is marked as '00:00'?

Comment: @aynber It is am.. but i dont specifically provide it with am or pm i just give is 12:00

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the 12-hour system for $time_in & $time_out because by 12:00 you seem to mean midnight.

The BETWEEN condition is not met because "12:00" is bigger than "03:00" and MySQL will never return any data in that case.

You would need to first translate '12' to '00' when 12:00am is meant.

Or you should find another way to let MySQL know that you mean 12:00am instead of 12:00pm.

Besides, how do you differentiate between for example 4am and 4pm?

I am just happy I always use the 24-hour system where 12:00am is just 00:00.

Comment: yes, clients wanted to have 12 hour format with no am or pm.. If they insert 7:00 - 3:00 they mean 7 at am and 3 at pm.. I should've converted it to 24 hour format when I was saving would've been easire

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for overlapping periods, try this:

```php
$time_in = $time_in.':00';
$time_out = $time_out.':00';
$query->where(function ($mainQuery) use ($time_in, $time_out) {
            $mainQuery->where(function ($firstQuery) use ($time_in, $time_out) {
                // starts within period
                $firstQuery->where('time_in', '>=', $time_in)
                    ->where('time_in', '<', $time_out);

            })->orWhere(function ($secondQuery) use ($time_in, $time_out) {
                // ends within period
                $secondQuery->where('time_out', '>', $time_in)
                    ->where('time_out', '<=', $time_out);

            })
            ->orWhere(function ($thirdQuery) use ($time_in, $time_out) {
                // starts before period, ends after it
                $thirdQuery->where('time_in', '<', $time_in)
                    ->where('time_out', '>', $time_out);
            });
        });
```

In the example above, my periods are exclusive on `time_out` which means

`time_in <= in_period < time_out`

This way you can have two periods one after the other having `period1_time_out = period2_time_in`.

Comment: @ReyYoung what format are your fields `time_in` and `time_out` in your Database ?

Comment: i have datatype `time` in database

Comment: @ReyYoung Then the format need to be `HH:MM:SS`, try adding `:00` to the end of `$time_in` & `$time_out`.

Comment: can I use something like this TIME_FORMAT("19:30:10", "%H %i %s")

Comment: @ReyYoung `TIME_FORMAT()` is for selecting a `time` datatype field with a specific format. it wont help you here. Can you tell me what's in `$time_out` ?

Comment: doesn't seem to work couldn't fetch data same problem. I have updated my query please check.

Comment: @ReyYoung have you tried my solution, updated the answer.

Comment: yes thanks for your help. I've fixed it. the conditions were giving false. for example: In my db: `time_in = 11:00` and `time_out = 7:00` here i'm think of `7:00 ` as pm and 11 as am. so when I try to check it with `time_in = 12:00 >= 11:00 & time_in <= 7:00` i was getting false. so I fetched all the data., maped over them and converted them to 24 hours format.. thanks